# Congestion in the "Edit questions and answers" privilege tracker box

Tags: support, design, profile-page, privileges

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The text touches the top and bottom of the box and it doesn't look good...

Can this be fixed? As in, can the box be expanded to include a few more characters?

If the box cannot be expanded, then I suggest changing the "**and**" to "**&**" in the same way as the "Cast close & reopen votes" [privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

[image]